# Delegate method not called : IOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a `ConfirmClaimViewcontroller.h` which defines a delegate as:

```
@protocol ClaimConfirmedDelegate<NSObject>
@required
- (void) claimConfirmedDelegate : (NSInteger) tag;
@end

@interface ConfirmClaimControllerViewController : UIViewController{
    id <ClaimConfirmedDelegate> delegate;
}

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withTag:(NSInteger)tag;

@property(nonatomic,assign)id delegate;

@end
```

I define the delegate in `ClaimViewController.m` :

```
- (void) claimConfirmedDelegate:(NSInteger)tag{
    NSLog(@"Delegate called");
}
```

I call the `ConfirmClaimViewController` as below ( its a popup) :

```
   ConfirmClaimControllerViewController *confirmClaimController=[[ConfirmClaimControllerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConfirmClaim" bundle:nil withTag:sender.view.tag];
    confirmClaimController.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:confirmClaimController.view];
    [confirmClaimController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:confirmClaimController];
```

The popup has two buttons. One one of the button is clicked, this code is called :

```
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(claimConfirmed:)])
{
    [self.delegate claimConfirmedDelegate:self.tagId];
}


[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self removeFromParentViewController];
```

This is supposed to call the delegate method and then remove the child from view. Child gets removed but delegate is never called. I'm new to this  , any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check that the delegate is not nil.
most of the times, programers forget to set the delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(claimConfirmed:)])
```

Should be:

```
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(claimConfirmedDelegate:)])
```